# Nearly matches optional requirement in of protocol `JTCalendarDelegate`

Tags: swift4, jtcalendar

The following methods are throwing a warning and not working after converting/migrating to Swift 4.

```
public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareDayView dayView: UIView!)

public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, didTouchDayView dayView: UIView!)
```

See the images for reference:

[image: "nearly matches optional requirement" warning]

[image: "nearly matches optional requirement" warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 4, these two methods have different types for the `dayView` argument (`(UIView & JTCalendarDay)!` instead of `UIView!`):

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareDayView dayView: (UIView & JTCalendarDay)!)

func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, didTouchDayView dayView: (UIView & JTCalendarDay)!)
```

Comment: @AbhishekMitra You welcome! A tip for the future: start typing the most typical/unique part of a function (for e.g. "prepareDayView") and Xcode will suggest the correct required function for you.